# Dump all values in .vars in Freemarker

Tags: java, jsp, freemarker

I'm attempting to dump all the variables available to my freemarker templates. I'm attempting to use something like:

```
<#list .vars?keys as prop>
${prop} = ${.vars.get(prop)}
```

`</#list>`

I read in the documentation that .vars doesn't support the keys functionality however I'm using the above to show what I'm trying to do.

This is my first day with Freemarker so any advice would be great.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19039195/355438) answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can list all the variables available to the template.  I know you [can't](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/app_faq.html#faq_question_26) list them in Java.

FreeMarker is very well [documented](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html).  Check out the part on [special variables in FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_specvar.html).

If it's any consolation,  you can access the local variables,

```
<#assign someVar = 12>
<#list .main?keys as var>
    ${var}
</#list>
```

which outputs

```
someVar
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I did find Environment.getKnownVariableNames(), however I don't know if will do what I want and I can't seem to figure out how to get the environment :-P

Comment: I looked at that as well, but found it did not function as I expected it would.  One theory I had, was that perhaps Freemarker does not have a list of the variables in the data_model, because at runtime it just attempts reflections to retrieve them from a get method.  However I don't know the freemarker code well enough to verify this.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I was wondering about how to output the values of such keys which names have . (period) in it. 

Freemarker was trying to evaluate the right hand side of . as a property of some object.

I was able to achieve this by using .data_model special variable.