# What is the equivalent of PHP's print_r() in FreeMarker Template Engine?

Tags: java, php, freemarker

For debugging purposes, I want to be able to get a representation of an entire object passed as a parameter to a macro.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion on stackoverflow in similar term here:
[Dump all values in .vars in Freemarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751230/dump-all-values-in-vars-in-freemarker)

Hope this will help.