# does freemarker support show all variable in data-model?

Tags: freemarker

I want to see all variables in freemarker data-model, just like struts2 `debug` tag to show value stack.

Is there a way for freemarker to do this ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's no universal solution possible for that, but you can try

```
<#list .data_model?keys as key>
  ${key}
</#list>
```

This works if the data-model is just a usual `Map` or JavaBean, but for more sophisticated data-models it's up to the data-model implementation if it supports `?keys` and if it indeed returns everything.

You also have the variables that you set in the templates, which can be listed like above, only instead of `.data_model` use `.globals`, `.namespace` (which means the current template namespace) and `.locals`.

You may also have `Configuration`-level shared variables, and there's no way to list those purely from FTL (you could write a custom `TemplateMethodModel` for it that reads `Configuration.getSharedVariableNames()` though, and call it from the template).

Of course, ideally, FreeMarker should have a `<#show_variables>` directive or something, that does a best effort to show all this... but sadly there is no such thing yet.

Comment: I got `Expected an extended hash, but this evaluated to a hash` error. Does it mean the `.data_model` hash doesn't support the ?keys hash operator?

Comment: Yes. Non-extend hashes can't enumerate their own keys or values.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It saved a LOT of time debugging freemarker

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

An even more detailed way would be this macro:

```
<#macro dump_object object debug=false>
    <#compress>
        <#if object??>
            <#attempt>
                <#if object?is_node>
                    <#if object?node_type == "text">${object?html}
                    <#else>&lt;${object?node_name}<#if object?node_type=="element" && object.@@?has_content><#list object.@@ as attr>
                        ${attr?node_name}="${attr?html}"</#list></#if>&gt;
                        <#if object?children?has_content><#list object?children as item>
                            <@dump_object object=item/></#list><#else>${object}</#if> &lt;/${object?node_name}&gt;</#if>
                <#elseif object?is_method>
                    #method
                <#elseif object?is_sequence>
                        [<#list object as item><@dump_object object=item/><#if !item?is_last>, </#if></#list>]
                <#elseif object?is_hash_ex>
                        {<#list object as key, item>${key?html}=<@dump_object object=item/><#if !item?is_last>, </#if></#list>}
                <#else>
                    "${object?string?html}"
                </#if>
            <#recover>
                <#if !debug><!-- </#if>LOG: Could not parse object <#if debug><pre>${.error}</pre><#else>--></#if>
            </#attempt>
        <#else>
            null
        </#if>
    </#compress>
</#macro>

<@dump_object object=.data_model/>
```

This gives you a full dump of your data model.

Comment: Had to replace some values to make it json5 compatible, but works like charm

Answer (score 1):

Here is @lemhannes macro definition modified to emit JSON. Lightly tested on a fairly simple datamodel

```
<#macro dump_object object debug=false>
  <#compress>
    <#if object??>
      <#attempt>
        <#if object?is_node>
          <#if object?node_type == "text">${object?json_string}
          <#else>${object?node_name}<#if object?node_type=="element" && object.@@?has_content><#list object.@@ as attr>
            "${attr?node_name}":"${attr?json_string}"</#list></#if>
             <#if object?children?has_content><#list object?children as item>
                <@dump_object object=item/></#list><#else>${object}</#if>"${object?node_name}"</#if>
             <#elseif object?is_method>
               "#method"
             <#elseif object?is_sequence>
               [<#list object as item><@dump_object object=item/><#if !item?is_last>, </#if></#list>]
             <#elseif object?is_hash_ex>
               {<#list object as key, item>"${key?json_string}":<@dump_object object=item/><#if !item?is_last>, </#if></#list>}
             <#else>
              "${object?string?json_string}"
             </#if>
      <#recover>
        <#if !debug>"<!-- </#if>LOG: Could not parse object <#if debug><pre>${.error}</pre><#else>-->"</#if>
      </#attempt>
    <#else>
      null
    </#if>
  </#compress>
</#macro>
```