# STM32 CubeMX custom code generation

Tags: code-generation, freemarker, stm32

I'm use [STM32CubeMX](https://my.st.com/content/my_st_com/en/products/development-tools/software-development-tools/stm32-software-development-tools/stm32-configurators-and-code-generators/stm32cubemx.html#getsoftware-scroll) and trying to [generate my custom code](https://my.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/10/c5/1a/43/3a/70/43/7d/DM00104712.pdf/files/DM00104712.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00104712.pdf) *(UM1718 page 141)* with tables of used periferals. It is easy to have constant tables in flash with periferals handles and instances grouped by intended use. For example this header file:

**some.h:**

```
/* TIM table */
#define EM_TIM1     0       // index
#define EM_TIM6     1

#define TIM_CNT     2       // count

#define TIM_0_INST      TIM1        // table of instaces
#define TIM_1_INST      TIM6

extern TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;     // table of handles
extern TIM_HandleTypeDef htim6;

#define TIM_0_HNDL      htim1       // table of handles
#define TIM_1_HNDL      htim6

struct tim_tab_s {
    TIM_TypeDef * inst;
    TIM_HandleTypeDef * hndl;
};

extern struct tim_tab_s const tim_tab[TIM_CNT];
```

I have generate with this custom template:

**some_h.ftl:**

```
[#ftl]
[#list configs as dt]
[#assign data = dt]
[#assign peripheralParams =dt.peripheralParams]
[#assign peripheralGPIOParams =dt.peripheralGPIOParams]
[#assign peripheralDMAParams =dt.peripheralDMAParams]
[#assign peripheralNVICParams =dt.peripheralNVICParams]
[#assign usedIPs =dt.usedIPs]
[#assign ip_pref = "EM_"]
[#-- ip desrcibe grpName  varName instType       hndlType --]
[#assign ip_tim =["TIM",  "htim", "TIM_TypeDef", "TIM_HandleTypeDef" ]]
[#assign ip_grps = [ip_tim]]
[#list ip_grps as ip_group]
    [#assign ip_grp = ip_group[0]]
    [#assign ip_var = ip_group[1]]
    [#assign ip_instType = ip_group[2]]
    [#assign ip_hndlType = ip_group[3]]
    /* ${ip_grp} table */
    [#assign ip_id = 0]                      [#-- IPs Index --]
    [#list usedIPs as ip]
        [#if peripheralParams.get(ip).entrySet()?size>0&&ip?contains(ip_grp)]
            #define ${ip_pref}${ip} ${ip_id}[#if ip_id == 0]  // index[/#if]
            [#assign ip_id = ip_id + 1]
        [/#if]
    [/#list][#-- list IPs --]
    #n
    #define ${ip_grp}_CNT ${ip_id}  // count
    #n
    [#assign ip_id = 0]               [#-- IPs Instaces --]
    [#list usedIPs as ip]
        [#if peripheralParams.get(ip).entrySet()?size>0&&ip?contains(ip_grp)]
            #define ${ip_grp}_${ip_id}_INST ${ip}[#if ip_id == 0]  // table of instaces[/#if]
            [#assign ip_id = ip_id + 1]
        [/#if]
    [/#list][#-- list IPs --]
    #n
    [#assign ip_id = 0]               [#-- IPs HAL handles declar --]
    [#list usedIPs as ip]
        [#if peripheralParams.get(ip).entrySet()?size>0&&ip?    contains(ip_grp)]
            extern ${ip_hndlType} ${ip_var}${ip.replace(ip_grp,"")};[#if ip_id == 0] // table of handles[/#if]
            [#assign ip_id = ip_id + 1]
        [/#if]
    [/#list][#-- list IPs --]
    #n
    [#assign ip_id = 0]                [#-- IPs HAL handles --]
    [#list usedIPs as ip]
        [#if peripheralParams.get(ip).entrySet()?size>0&&ip?contains(ip_grp)]
            #define ${ip_grp}_${ip_id}_HNDL ${ip_var}${ip.replace(ip_grp,"")}[#if ip_id == 0] // table of handles[/#if]
            [#assign ip_id = ip_id + 1]
        [/#if]
    [/#list][#-- list IPs --]
[/#list][#-- list ip_grps --]
[/#list][#-- list configs --]
```

I havn't work with freemarker until this moment.

And **my problem that I can't found way to extract more information** from this data model:

- **about handles types and names** (I have simply declared it `[#assign ip_tim =["TIM",  "htim", "TIM_TypeDef", "TIM_HandleTypeDef" ]]`),
- **about GPIOs that not associated with any periferals, but initialized and have lables** (I have no idea there).

As described in UM1718:

> The user template file must be compatible with STM32CubeMX data model. This means that the template must start with the following lines:
>
> ```
> [#ftl]
> [#list configs as dt]
> [#assign data = dt]
> [#assign peripheralParams =dt.peripheralParams]
> [#assign peripheralGPIOParams =dt.peripheralGPIOParams]
> [#assign usedIPs =dt.usedIPs]
> ```
>
> and end with
>
> ```
> [/#list]
> ```

**Is this mean that there no way to extract necessary information (mostly about GPIOs)?**

**Or how I can check this?** I have try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497777/freemarker-iterating-over-hashmap-keys/1497802#1497802) to describe data model but found only list of GPIO ports.

Comment: If it's not documented what the data-model contains, you could check the Java code that calls FreeMarker and what it passes to it. Looking for a `Template.process` call probably helps finding it. Or, you could try dumping the data-model: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028337/does-freemarker-support-show-all-variable-in-data-model?lq=1

Comment: @ddekany, I have no access to STM32CubeMX sources, and as I wrote in my question: I have tried to dump data-model same way as you say (see lst line of my question). So as I understand ther only two ways and all of them can't help me?

Comment: You could examine the data-model in Java. Put a break-point on `freemarker.core.Environment.process`, and then look at the `rootDataModel` field. It will be some sort of `TemplateModel`, but inside that you may find (pieces of) the original Java objects. As of you don't have source code for STM32CubeMX, decompilers like JAD might helps.

Comment: I have tried to decompile CubeMX with JAD but i'm newbie with Java and didn't achieve success.

Comment: Sorry, it's not JAD, but JD... http://jd.benow.ca/

Answer (score 0):

This is response for ticket to ST support that I have open about month ago. So now it's one actual answer to my question.

> Dear Customer,
>
> unfortunately this feature is quite new, experimental and not well documented, so I'm not able to help you with this issue. The API might also be changed in future releases. If I understand it correctly, you are able to workaround this issue by defining the array manually.
>
> Best regards, ST MCU Support Team

I'm waiting for new releases!